# Wordpress theme integrate with rest api

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and a theme. When I hit home page it suppose to show products available in site, but is loading theme with default products came along with theme. I want to render my own products instead of theme products when I hit home page.

I do like to use existing rest web service to load that products from DB to show in theme home page.

I am new to wordpress and I need a way to achieve that requirement.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: which theme do you use ?

Comment: it is "Shop Isle" by "theme isle"

Comment: With this theme you can configure the home page in "Appearence" => "Customise"